# Appropriate age grouping for studying linguistic development

Tags: developmental-psychology, linguistics, sociology, cognitive-development, psycholinguistics

I am publishing a survey on a crowdsourcing platform to study how people of different ages perceive certain aspects of non-literal language. The platform allows me to target people with ages in specific ranges.

My questions is: what are appropriate age ranges? Is there any literature that would, for instance, say the linguistic perception is similar for people between 25 and 34-years old? Or is 25 and 44 years old a better range? All in all, which age partitioning makes more sense in terms of linguistic development, perception of non-literal language, or any other related criterion?

For instance: 18-24, 25-34, 34-44, 45-54, >65? Or maybe 18-24, 25-44, >45?

Comment: You say the platform allows you to target people with ages in specific ranges, but does it require you to do so?  If you can instead collect their age as part of the survey, then why not avoid age ranges altogether, and just plot the results on a graph instead?  I don't see why you would want to bucket them into ranges unless there was some reason you haven't disclosed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do need to bucket them. I am simply looking for a way of bucketing that makes sense in the context of my experiment (similar way of using language especially non-literal language).